# Вывод дынных в ListView

Tags: xml, android, парсер, java

Здравствуйте, опять нужна помощь.

Проблема: приложение парсит сайт, выводит данные в listview, а в ListView в одной "позиции" надо вывести сразу 3 числа, каждое число по-разному оформляется и т.д.

Как сделать, собственно, саму эту позицию и ее оформление? Через xml.

Заранее спасибо.

**UPD**

Не в одной строке, там надо в разные части этой самой позиции, с разным оформлением и разным цветом текста, и у самой позиции оформление. Это как сделать?

Comment: @DenShDen, покажите пример, как это должно выглядеть. Нарисуйте в фотошопе, либо в html.

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20custom%20listview&es_th=1

Comment: Вам нужно создать кастомный ArrayAdapter. Весь процесс описан тут
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832335/android-custom-row-item-for-listview

Answer (score 1):

В одной позиции надо нарисовать три входящих числа? Сделай класс, который агрегирует три числа, и переопредели метод `toString()`, например. А в методе

`return "val1:"+integer1+"...val2:"+integer2+"...val3:"+integer3`.

Конечно, конкатенацией не пользуйся, а приделай StringBuilder.

Comment: да не, не в одной строке.. там надо в разные части этой самой позиции, с разным оформлением и разным цветом текста.и у самой позиции оформление. Это как сделать?